# Substitution rule for integrals: $\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} f^{''}(t)(x_0+h-t)dt = \frac {-1}{2}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} f^{''}(t)d(x_0+h-t)^2$ clarification

Tags: calculus

Considering a continuous function $F :\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$, as part of a proof I encounter the following equality:

$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} f^{''}(t)(x_0+h-t)dt = \frac {-1}{2}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} f^{''}(t)d(x_0+h-t)^2$.

I am familiar with basic substitution tactics for integrals, for instance if $u=x+1$, then $\int_{0}^{1}x+1dx = \int_{1}^{2}udu$, but the example above is confusing me. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt oops sorry will edit.

Comment: $$\int_1^2u\mathrm du=\int_0^1(x+1)~\mathrm d(x+1)=\int_0^1(x+1)~\mathrm dx$$ In general: $$\frac{\mathrm df(x)}{\mathrm dx}=f'(x)\implies\mathrm df(x)=f'(x)~\mathrm dx$$ and $$\int g(u)~\mathrm du=\int g(f(x))~\mathrm df(x)$$

Comment: This is simply change of variable: view $x_0+h$ as a constant (which is irrelevant to your integration), it is obvious that $d(x_0+h-t)^2=-2(x_0+h-t)dt$.

Comment: @user65018 what is the substitution?